# Differenz between blank and empty in aws vtl

Tags: amazon-web-services, vtl

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/utility-helpers-in-util.html#utility-helpers-in-null-behavior

Whats the differenc between `blank` and `empty`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blank:

In the context of strings or text, "blank" often means a string that contains only whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) with no visible content.

Empty:

In programming, "empty" is often used to describe variables, arrays, or data structures that have no elements or content.